# problem with checked all checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When someone clicks on first `input:checkbox`, I want my code to check all checkboxes, but my code doesn't work correctly:

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/

```
$('.table_show tr input:first').live('click',function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $(".table_show tr input[name=checked[]]").each(function(){
            if (!$(this).prop('checked') == isChecked) {
                $(this).parent().click();
            }
        });
    });
```

What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Could you put a little more effort into your questions before posting? I understand that English is not your first language, but the word "checked" is spelt correctly in your code  five times, yet incorrectly outside of it. You also haven't shown any sign of attempting to debug this yourself; you probably could have determined that it was an issue with your selector. This seems like laziness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with your code is that you dont quote the name selector properly:
change

```
$(".table_show tr input[name=checked[]]")
```

to

```
$(".table_show tr input[name='checked[]']")
```

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/5/

also, your UX could be better. Usually when the user manually checks all the checkboxes, the checkall checkbox should become checked, and when user unchecks one box so that "all" arent checked, the checkall box should become unchecked

**edit:**
The answer to the 2nd question is that you must maintain a count of total number of checkboxes, and when that number is checked, the checkall checkbox must be checked, otherwise it must be unchecked. do this check every time user checks a checkbox manually. Sorry, i dont have the time to provide that code right now.

Comment: This recommend that you told me, how is it? (did can give me example in same http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/5/ ?)

Comment: @KateThompson: You just unaccepted this answer so that you can pressure him into giving you an answer to a **different question**? That's totally unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
$(".table_show tr input[name=checked[]]")
```

jQuery sees this as looking for the name `checked[`, because the first `]` terminates the name.

You need to escape it with a backslash, which itself needs to be escaped with another backslash.

```
$(".table_show tr input[name=checked\\[\\]]")
```

After replacing this, your code works.

*Edit:* I'll leave this answer here because it works and may be useful for similar problems, but mkoryak's answer is the proper way to deal with this.

Comment: Or, just use `[name='checked']`. Those `'` are required by the documentation in fact. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ `Quotes are mandatory.`

Comment: @pimvdb: Good point. I'm now surprised that escaping worked, given what the documentation said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/8/

```
$('.table_show tr').live('click',function(e) {
    var wasCheckboxClicked = $(e.target).is('input[name=delete[]]'),
        row = $(this),
        checkBox = row.find("input:checkbox"),
        shouldCheck = checkBox.prop('checked') == wasCheckboxClicked;
    if (!row.is(':first-child')) {
        row.css('backgroundColor', shouldCheck?"#ffd6c1":"");
        checkBox.prop('checked', shouldCheck);
    }
});

$('.table_show th input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.table_show td input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').parent().click();
    }
    else {
        $('.table_show td input[type=checkbox]:checked').parent().click();
    }
});

$('.table_show td input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var checkboxes = $('.table_show td input[type=checkbox]');
        if(checkboxes.length == checkboxes.filter(':checked').length) {
            $('.table_show th input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    } 
    else {
        console.log($('.table_show th input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked'));
       $('.table_show th input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```